# How to get all table and column names from database in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am working on a module where I want to do dynamic dependent dropdown table and column name functionality.

Ex. Fetch all table names and display it in dropdown fields and after selection of particular table I want to display its all column name again in dropdown field.

The issues are:

1) How to fetch all table name from db?

2) and how to fetch all column name from table?

I tried few articles and forums like http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5920-how-can-i-get-the-actual-full-table-name/
but its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's quite simple, using an instance of the `CDbTableSchema` class:

```
echo 'Name: ', $tbl->name, ' (raw: ', $tbl->rawName, ')';
echo 'Fields: ', implode(', ', $tbl->columnNames);
```

And so on. [There's a lot of methods and properties for this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbTableSchema)
To get *all* tables, just use the `CDbSchema` class [docs here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbSchema).

the `CDbSchema` class has both the public `tableNames` property (an array of all tbl namnes) and a `tables` property, containing all meta-data. That's all, really.

To get to all these instances, the following code should suffice:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;//get connection
$dbSchema = $connection->schema;
//or $connection->getSchema();
$tables = $dbSchema->getTables();//returns array of tbl schema's
foreach($tables as $tbl)
{
    echo $tbl->rawName, ':<br/>', implode(', ', $tbl->columnNames), '<br/>';
}
```

To create  a dropdown list, you simply use the *standard `CHtml` object*:

```
$options = array();
foreach($tables as $tbl)
{//for example
    $options[$tbl->rawName] = $tbl->name;
}
$dropDown = CHtml::dropDownList('tables',$tables[0]->rawName, $options);
```

Please, spend some time [Reading the manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail), it's all there. I haven't used `Yii` that extensively, well, I haven't used it at all, to be honest, yet it only took me 5 minutes to work this out. Just look at the [source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/tree/1.1.14/framework)! Each and every method/class/property has a link to the exact line in the corresponding file!
Before asking others to figure something out for you, *put in some effort*.

Comment: How can I display all table names in dropdown?

Comment: @Sky: By reading the bloody manual, like I did... It took me a mere 5 minutes, but I've added my findings to my answer

Answer (score 4):

fetch all column name from table:

```
TableName::model()->getTableSchema()->getColumnNames();
```

It'll return an array containing all the column names of TableName.

Answer (score 0):

fetch all column name and labels:

```
$fields=Tablename::attributeLabels();
foreach($fields as $key=>$value){
    echo "column name : ".$key." and label ".$value."<br/>";
}
```

it will display all fieldname and label value from modal.....

Comment: This will throw an Error in Yii2 Tablename::model()->attributeLabels() . Just remove the model()  it should be like Tablename:attributeLabels()

Answer (score 0):

To get both Tables and Columns refer [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21981452/5692821), I have pasted the sample code here below, please visit that answer for more explanations.

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;//get connection
$dbSchema = $connection->schema;
//or $connection->getSchema();
$tables = $dbSchema->getTables();//returns array of tbl schema's
 foreach($tables as $tbl)
  {
    echo $tbl->rawName, ':<br/>', implode(', ', $tbl->columnNames), '<br/>';
  }
```