# Get all table names in yii

Tags: mysql, database, yii

How to get all table names in yii?

The sql query in mySQL is `SHOW TABLES`.
I tried:

```
$sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
$tables = Yii::app()->db
         ->createCommand($sql)
         ->queryAll();
print_r($tables);
```

It throws an error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement:
CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "SHOW": syntax error.
The SQL statement executed was: SHOW TABLES
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this one:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;//get connection
$dbSchema = $connection->schema;
//or $connection->getSchema();
$tables = $dbSchema->getTables();//returns array of tbl schema's
foreach($tables as $tbl)
{
    echo $tbl->rawName, ':<br/>', implode(', ', $tbl->columnNames), '<br/>';
}
```

**Refer:**[How to get all table and column names from database in Yii Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608531/how-to-get-all-table-and-column-names-from-database-in-yii-framework)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use yii then Mani`s answer is correct. If you want to get table names using create Command then you can use

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
$tables = Yii::app()->db
         ->createCommand($sql)
         ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple is simple:

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->db->schema->getTableNames();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbSchema - here look for detail